# jquery show hide div's with a href tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have some jquery which reveals and hides new div's based on which button is pressed. Rather than buttons i would like to insert my own text/image and have them work in the same way, revealing and hiding the new windows.

Here is the jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".buttons").click(function () {
        var divname= this.value;
          $("#"+divname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
        });

      });
</script>
```

Here is the code for one of the buttons which i would like changed to a a href tag.

```
<input type="button" id="button1" class="buttons" value="div1"></input>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Pia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `data()` method - http://api.jquery.com/data/ - to store arbitrary data on the anchor element (the div ID) and then use that value to show the proper div:

```
<div id="div1">div one</div>
<div id="div2">div two</div>
<a href="#" class="abuttons" data-divid="div1">link</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".abuttons").click(function () {
        var idname= $(this).data('divid');
        $("#"+idname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

If you want to show two div's using a class name instead of an ID, store the class name on the achor tag, set the same class on each of the divs you want to show, and reference it in jQuery using a `.` instead of a `#`

```
<div id="div1" class="divclass">div one</div>
<div id="div2" class="divclass">div two</div>

<a href="#" class="abuttons" data-divclass="divclass">link</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".abuttons").click(function () {
        var classname= $(this).data('divclass');
        $("."+classname).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think you would want to use the `data` attribute to access non-standard data storage elements. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: That will let you set key/value pairs on the element, but you would still need to set them somewhere. You need some sort of identifying element on the anchor to do that - it could be a class or ID, but using an arbitrary element will work as well, though you are correct that it is non-standard.

Comment: You set it in the HTML, right? `<a href="#" class=".abuttons" data-div="div1">link</a>`

Comment: Hi. This doesn't seem to work for me. I updated my jquery code and changed `<input type="button" id="button1" class="buttons" value="div1"></input>` to `<a href="#" class=".abuttons" data-div="div1">link</a>` however this did not return anything when i tested it. Here is my 1st div code: `<div id="div1" style="display:none">
Hello World</div>` Can you please confirm this works for you? Thanks. Pia @Palpatim @doublesharp

Comment: You don't want the `class` attribute to have a leading "." in your anchor tags. So change `<a href="#" class=".abuttons" data-div="div1">link</a>` to `<a href="#" class="abuttons" data-div="div1">link</a>` See a working example (structured slightly differently than your example) here: http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/bYfpB/

Comment: Great that works! Thanks for your help. I have one more question. Is it possible to reveal 2! different div's at once using one href? Thanks. Pia @Palpatim

Comment: It depends on what you mean specifically, but "yes". You could use `data-div1` and `data-div2` on the anchor to reference two different IDs for example (the jQuery would need to be updated to also show the new div). You could also use classes instead of IDs on the div and use one data-div and jQuery call to show both at once.

Comment: Hi. I attempted using classes rather than id's but this broke the script. Sorry i'm not so experienced in css and jquery. Can you please update the code for this new feature? Thanks again. Pia @doublesharp

Comment: Updated the answer to include a code sample using class names instead of IDs.

Comment: Wonderful. That works exactly how i want it to. Thanks heaps for your time. Pia @doublesharp

Comment: Instead of using the data field, why not just use the already-existing href field in the anchor. Here's a demo https://jsfiddle.net/bessppxz/